# Is a modifying operation thread safe on a List if the underlying datastracture is CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Tags: java, multithreading, copyonwritearraylist

I want to make my modifying operations thread safe, while also adhering to best practices regarding the design of the application.

I have let's say a `Zoo` class that manages the animals within it, like adding a new `Animal` to the zoo, removing one and so on, and I want these operations to be thread safe. For simplicity I have a `private List<Animal> animals` variable in the zoo. My first thought was to initialize the `animals` variable as a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` object within the constructor, whenever a new Zoo object is created, like so:

```
private List<Animal> animals;

public Zoo() {
    this.animals = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
}

public Zoo(List<Animal> animals) {
    this();
    addAnimals(animals);
}

public void addAnimals(Collection<Animal> animalsToAdd) {
    animals.addAll(animalsToAdd);
}
```

As far as I have understood, the methods of `CopyOnWriteArrayList` are thread safe, but can I achieve thread safety this way, i.e: by having the underlying datastructure be a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, while keeping the reference variable as a `List`? Or making the `List<Animal> animals` variable volatile and the methods in question `synchronize`d, would be a better option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is threadsafe as is. You'd only need to consider making `animals` volatile and/or adding your own synchronization if you were changing the `this.animals` reference with `this.animals = ...`. If you simply  set it once in the constructor and never change it again then you're already good to go.